# Is there a way to find the x-intercept of graph in labview

Tags: matlab, labview

I needed to know the interception point of graph plotted in the MATLAB based on the data without the knowledge to its function and output the acquired coordinate to the labview program.Is it possible?

Comment: You can check [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100921-how-do-i-extract-data-points-from-a-plot) how to extract the data points from the graph. With the points, look for the interval where the function changes sign and maybe [interpolate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) to get the x-intercept.

Comment: Sorry but what I mean is that I plot a few curves on the same image using few arrays and I wanted to find the interception point of these curves.

Comment: you should provide us with the data you have, a minimal reproducible example and the code with what you've tried so far and what problem you have

Comment: Finding intersection points in LabVIEW is possible. Finding intersection points in MATLAB is possible. Why on earth are you trying to send the result from one platform to the other?